# SQL Query include row when at Least one of three fields is not null

Tags: sql, null, presto

I would like to include a record in my query when, from a certain three fields, at least one of the three is not null.

I'm probably overthinking this, as there are other "AND" clauses that need to be present.

Do I just need to use parentheses?
This is a Presto query by the way, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be to test all three columns directly with an `or` operator between them. As you noticed, you should surround the entire condition with parentheses to avoid bugs related to the fact that the `and` logical operator in other conditions has a higher precedence:

```
(col1 IS NOT NULL OR col2 IS NOT NULL OR col3 IS NOT NULL)
```

A more elegant solution, however, could be to `coalesce` all three columns and check the result:

```
COALESCE(col1, col2, col3) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

That is simple. Use parentheses when mixing `AND` and `OR`:

```
WHERE (col1 IS NOT NULL OR col2 IS NOT NULL OR col3 IS NOT NULL)
AND ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check each column with `IS NOT NULL`:

```
col1 IS NOT NULL OR col2 IS NOT NULL OR col3 IS NOT NULL
```

Or:

```
NOT (col1 IS NULL AND col2 IS NULL AND col3 IS NULL)
```

Or with `COALESCE()`:

```
COALESCE(col1, col2, col3) IS NOT NULL
```